# What are the allowed values for remote_local_fallback_strategy

Tags: bazel

In the command line reference for Bazel - https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html- there is an option called "remote_local_fallback_strategy". It's description is

> The strategy to use when remote execution has to fallback to local execution.

Apparently the default value is "local", which sounds like it means that a failed target will run on the local machine without sandboxing. What are the other allowed values for this option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, `--remote_local_fallback_strategy` can take the same values as [`--spawn_strategy`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#flag--spawn_strategy). There isn't a definitive list anywhere, since the set possible values depends on the configuration of Bazel. Probably the only interesting non-default value of `--remote_local_fallback_strategy` is `sandboxed`, which will cause actions that can't be executed remotely to be run in a [local sandbox](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#sandboxing).